# Is there a native Mac app that allows you to see all outbound network traffic similar to a web browser inspector?

Tags: networking, traffic, network-traffic

Is there a native Mac app that allows you to see all outbound network traffic?

Much in the same way I can open Google Chrome to see the network tab, I'd like to see the same for my Mac.

For example, when I do git push on my terminal, I'd like to see what the request looks like (body, header, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Tools like this are called packet sniffers or protocol analyzers. `tcpdump` is a built-in command line tool for this, and the cross platform open source GUI app WireShark runs fine on macOS, although its GUI is not terribly Mac-line.

Note that a lot of your traffic is encrypted at the application level, so you might not get to see many of the protocol details you might like to see.